# Distributed `itertools.combinations`

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.combinations` inconjunction with `itertools.cycle` to create a set of objects to assign to another list of objects. Sadly if the lists are not the same length or evenly divisible then the first item in the list gets un-evenly weighted.

```
cycle_of_combinations = cycle(combinations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2))
#(('A', 'B'), 
# ('A', 'C'), 
# ('A', 'D'), 
# ('B', 'C'), 
# ('B', 'D'), 
# ('C', 'D'))

assigned_combinations = []
for _ in range(0, 9):
   assigned_combinations.append(cycle_of_combinations.next())

# assigned_combinations = [
# ('A', 'B'), 
# ('A', 'C'), 
# ('A', 'D'), 
# ('B', 'C'), 
# ('B', 'D'), 
# ('C', 'D'),
# ('A', 'B'), 
# ('A', 'C'), 
# ('A', 'D')]
```

In the above example combinations that contain 'A' are over-represented. Is there a quick way to better evenly distribute the combinations?

Here's an example of a set that would be more evenly distributed, in this set I've selected every 2nd item until there are 9 items:

```
# assigned_combinations = [
# ('A', 'B'), 
# ('A', 'D'), 
# ('B', 'D'), 
# ('A', 'C'), 
# ('B', 'C'), 
# ('C', 'D'),
# ('A', 'B'), 
# ('A', 'D'), 
# ('B', 'D')]
```

Comment: @user2357112 how are you counting? I get `'A'` showing up in 3 of 6 combinations, with `'B'`, `'C'`, and `'D'` all 3 of 6 as well.

Comment: Why did you cut off `assigned_combinations` at the 6th element? That confusingly hides the effect you're trying to stop.

Comment: Similarly, your comment under `cycle` hides the fact that you actually created a cycle (and also naming that variable `cycle` hides the `cycle` function you imported).

Comment: sorry @user2357112, must have got cut in my editing by accidentally. I've also renamed cycle for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate enough full cycles to cover the needed list then shuffle and trim to size. The returned list will be a bit different each time and you will still get some over representation (its inevitable with mismatched sizes and random.shuffle may make it more pronounced from time to time).

```
import math
import itertools
import random

def get_combos(somelist, length, count):
    combos = list(itertools.combinations(somelist, length))
    combos = combos * math.ceil(count/len(combos))
    random.shuffle(combos)
    return combos[:count]

for item in get_combos(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2, 9):
    print(item)
```